# How to upgrade sed on RHEL 8?

Tags: sed, rhel, upgrade, dependencies

I'm on a RHEL 8 system and by default `sed` 4.5 was installed.

```
[root@192 ~]# rpm -qf `which sed`
sed-4.5-2.el8.x86_64
[root@192 ~]#
```

Since I want to use the `--debug` option to debug some `sed` commands, I have to upgrade `sed`. When I try to uninstall `sed`, I found a lot of other packages depend on it:

```
[root@192 ~]# rpm -e sed
error: Failed dependencies:
    /bin/sed is needed by (installed) os-prober-1.74-6.el8.x86_64
    sed is needed by (installed) krb5-libs-1.18.2-5.el8.x86_64
    sed is needed by (installed) ca-certificates-2020.2.41-80.0.el8_2.noarch
    sed is needed by (installed) dracut-049-95.git20200804.el8.x86_64
    sed is needed by (installed) policycoreutils-2.9-9.el8.x86_64
    sed is needed by (installed) sane-backends-1.0.27-19.el8_2.1.x86_64
    sed is needed by (installed) authselect-libs-1.2.1-2.el8.x86_64
    sed is needed by (installed) open-vm-tools-11.1.0-2.el8.x86_64
    sed is needed by (installed) dhcp-client-12:4.3.6-41.el8.x86_64
    sed is needed by (installed) cups-filters-1.20.0-20.el8.x86_64
    sed is needed by (installed) nfs-utils-1:2.3.3-35.el8.x86_64
    sed is needed by (installed) authselect-compat-1.2.1-2.el8.x86_64
    sed is needed by (installed) autofs-1:5.1.4-43.el8.x86_64
    /usr/bin/sed is needed by (installed) groff-base-1.22.3-18.el8.x86_64
[root@192 ~]#
```

In this case, what's the proper way to upgrade `sed`? I also tried to install a new version directly:

```
[root@192 ~]# rpm -ivh https://download-ib01.fedoraproject.org/pub/fedora/linux/releases/35/Everything/aarch64/os/Packages/s/sed-4.8-8.fc35.aarch64.rpm
Retrieving https://download-ib01.fedoraproject.org/pub/fedora/linux/releases/35/Everything/aarch64/os/Packages/s/sed-4.8-8.fc35.aarch64.rpm
warning: /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.VumGnB: Header V4 RSA/SHA256 Signature, key ID 9867c58f: NOKEY
error: Failed dependencies:
    glibc >= 2.33.9000-43.fc35 is needed by sed-4.8-8.fc35.aarch64
    ld-linux-aarch64.so.1()(64bit) is needed by sed-4.8-8.fc35.aarch64
    ld-linux-aarch64.so.1(GLIBC_2.17)(64bit) is needed by sed-4.8-8.fc35.aarch64
    libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.33)(64bit) is needed by sed-4.8-8.fc35.aarch64
    libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.34)(64bit) is needed by sed-4.8-8.fc35.aarch64
    libselinux.so.1(LIBSELINUX_1.0)(64bit) is needed by sed-4.8-8.fc35.aarch64
[root@192 ~]#
```

But, as you can see, it also has some failed dependencies. Should I install these missing dependencies and try to install again?

### Update

As jsbillings pointed out in the comment, I was using the wrong architecture of package. Below is the output of installing a x86_64 package.

```
[root@192 ~]# rpm -ivh https://download-ib01.fedoraproject.org/pub/fedora/linux/releases/35/Everything/x86_64/os/Packages/s/sed-4.8-8.fc35.x86_64.rpm
Retrieving https://download-ib01.fedoraproject.org/pub/fedora/linux/releases/35/Everything/x86_64/os/Packages/s/sed-4.8-8.fc35.x86_64.rpm
warning: /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.FT7OI2: Header V4 RSA/SHA256 Signature, key ID 9867c58f: NOKEY
error: Failed dependencies:
    glibc >= 2.33.9000-43.fc35 is needed by sed-4.8-8.fc35.x86_64
    libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.33)(64bit) is needed by sed-4.8-8.fc35.x86_64
    libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.34)(64bit) is needed by sed-4.8-8.fc35.x86_64
    libselinux.so.1(LIBSELINUX_1.0)(64bit) is needed by sed-4.8-8.fc35.x86_64
[root@192 ~]#
```

Comment: You might get fewer dependency errors if you used an x86_64 package instead of the aarch64 package.  Aarch64 packages are ARM and not Intel/AMD CPUs.  ;)

Comment: @jsbillings Thank you! I'll give it a try.

Comment: It most likely won’t work, if the aarch64 package indicates it needs a newer glibc.

Comment: Yes, there's fewer dependency errors now. I updated the result to the question.

Comment: This might have worked if you rebuilt the `sed` RPM on your local box and then upgraded; as others noted the GLIBC version mismatched because the RPMs came from a too-new machine. That said, for a quick debug session, throwing it into a container is definitely the simpler solution.

Comment: Your best option would be to download the source rpm for a newer version of sed and build the package on your RHEL 8 system, so that it is linked with the version of glibc installed on YOUR system.  This may require installing compilers and library headers if they're not already installed.  BTW, there's a source rpm for sed 4.8.9 for Centos 9 at https://centos.pkgs.org/9-stream/centos-baseos-x86_64/sed-4.8-9.el9.x86_64.rpm.html - this may require a little tweaking to build on RHEL 8, but at least the packaging work has been done.

Comment: If you can't build a package for some reason, your second best option is to download the unpackaged upstream [sed source](https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/sed/), compile it, and install it under /usr/local (adjust your PATH to add /usr/local/bin/ if it isn't already in PATH).   Use [GNU Stow](https://www.gnu.org/software/stow/) or [CheckInstall](http://checkinstall.izto.org) to enable you to easily upgrade or uninstall it in future. I don't know if either `stow` or `checkinstall` are packaged for RHEL but if they are, you should install the package.

Comment: @cas Thanks for the suggestion! I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can’t install Fedora packages on RHEL.

Instead of trying to upgrade your `sed`, since you only want a newer version for its debugging capabilities, I recommend running a container:

```
sudo yum install podman
podman run -it --rm fedora:35
```

This will give you a Fedora container with a recent version of `sed`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! This may be the most hassle-free way to solve my problem.

Comment: Btw, do you mean it's technically not possible to install Fedora packages on RHEL or not suggested? I remember I have installed one called `xclip` with the command `rpm -ivh https://download-ib01.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/8/Everything/x86_64/Packages/x/xclip-0.13-8.el8.x86_64.rpm`.

Comment: EPEL packages are built to be installed on RHEL and clones.  You are trying to install a Fedora 35 sed package, which was built for packages in Fedora 35, not RHEL8.

Comment: If you are interested in Podman, I suggest investigating ‘toolbox’ (and ‘distrobox’) which integrates podman containers into a simple mechanism to use containers to run alternative runtime environments with your home directory.

Comment: @jsbillings Thanks for the explanation and suggestion!